# Next term in the pattern

Tags: puzzle

$22+22=4444$

$43+46=618191$

$77+77=?$

What should come in place of $?$

I cannot see any logic in $43+46=618191$. Is there any?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $43+46=618198$?

Comment: Why? What would be logic if it is $43+46=618198$?

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: @Mufasa It was asked in a campus placement paper.

Comment: @Mathematics Are you sure that $43+46=618191$

Comment: @Mufasa Yes I am sure in paper it was 618191.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your puzzle again if $43+46$ is actually $618198$

If not then expanding on @Daniel's comment

$$22+22=(\text{reverse digits}(2*2))(\text{reverse digits}(2*2))[22+22+(2*2-2*2)]=4444$$

$$43+46=(\text{reverse digits}(4*4))(\text{reverse digits}(3*6))[(43+46+\left(6*3-4*4\right))]=618191$$

So the number of $77+77=\text{reverse}(7*7)\text{Reverse}(7*7)\text{reverse}(77+77+\left(7*7-7*7\right))=9494154$

Comment: Actually it was asked in my campus placement exam so I cannot recheck it. But I am sure it was 618191

Comment: If so then you can check my answer.

Comment: I think @Arbuja has got the trick of how to get the last component of this puzzle - well done!

Answer (score 2):

If you had $43+46=618198$ then I can see the following pattern:
$$\color{red}{4}\color{blue}{3}+\color{red}{4}\color{blue}{6}=\color{red}{\text{reverse(4*4)}}\color{blue}{\text{reverse(3*6)}}\color{green}{\text{reverse(43+46)}}=\color{red}{61}\color{blue}{81}\color{green}{98}$$

Comment: But this is not a true answer; this should be a comment.

Comment: The same logic can be used to show $22+22=4444$ and hence also be used to calculate $77+77$. The OP didn't clearly state that my assumption of $43+46=618198$ was incorrect.

Comment: It seems convincing.

Comment: 'It's convincing' - but gives the incorrect answer for $43+46$? Is there a mistake in your question, if so then it would be convincing.